# GLSL 1.5 - rendering to different layers of texture array

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` and I do this:

**1.** Render everything I want to FBO to texture array

**2.** Sample that array in the "main stage" of rendering

To achieve the first goal I've added a little geometry shader with `gl_Layer` calls to each primitive. Also, I've implemented some, let me say, "translation" thing similar to [this Nvidia tutorial](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/opengl/src/cascaded_shadow_maps/doc/cascaded_shadow_maps.pdf) in my shaders that I use for the second stage of rendering.

So, what's ***my problem*** :

**Condition:** same vertices, same FBO, same shaders, same texture array

**1)** Rebinding rendering target multiply times in my FBO with `glFramebufferTextureLayer` calls works fine.

**2)** Saving texture array as `glFramebufferTexture` and only changing `gl_Layer` value leads to unexpected behaviour (first layer (0 in the code) is correct, every layer I try render next is invalid).

**3)** I don't want to **1)** , I want to do **2)** . *How do I do that?*

My shaders I use when rendering the FBO.

*//vertex shader*

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 orthoView;
in vec4 in_Position;

void main(void) { 
    gl_Position = orthoView * in_Position; 
}
```

*//geometry*

```
#version 150 core

uniform int lr;

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
out int gl_Layer;

void main(void){
//pass-thru!
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
  }
gl_Layer = lr;
EndPrimitive();
}
```

*//fragment is empty*

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone for help! My problem is solved now, here is my geometry shader:

```
#version 150 core

uniform int lr;

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main(void){
//pass-thru!
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    gl_Layer = lr;
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
  }

EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: Why are you re-declaring `gl_Layer` in the geometry shader?  It should be a built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gl_Layer`, like *all geometry shader outputs* is a per-vertex output. Which vertex controls the layer for a particular primitive is [implementation-defined](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Which_vertex). In your case, there's no reason not to set it in your loop, before the `EmitVertex` call.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually used gl_Layer before, but looking at the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_Layer.xml), it sounds like it is a per-vertex attribute (which is odd...).

```
 The actual layer used will come from one of the vertices in the primitive being shaded
```

So try to set the value inside the for loop, before the EmitVertex, maybe?